# How to navigate user controls view in wpf mvvm without datatemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am new at wpf. So I decided to make some basic mvvm wpf application for myself. My app contains two blocks: navigation block and content block. Navigation block contain some buttons to change content block view. As I said before I make MVVM app, so my views are user controls.
I googled how to make some navigation. So in my app I did this:
In main xml I wrote like:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainViewModel}">
    <Views:MainView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:PersonViewModel}">
    <Views:PersonView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:CompanyViewModel}">
    <Views:CompanyView />
</DataTemplate>
```

In My main ViewModel I putted CurrentViewModel parameter that keeps information about current viewModel (and view).

In main xaml I actually wrote (my content block):

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
```

So now I can switch views;

My main questions:

1. If I have many views it will be hard to write allways new Datatemplate in main xaml. If I have 50 views? How do not always write it?
2. Do I need to use Pages for navigation? (In catel, mmvm light they use usercontrolls not pages)
3. In catel I made navigation by using viewModeToViewConverter and no datatemplate in main xaml - how to make like this? I really can not understand how does it work.

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use one MainWindow and multiple UserControl for navigation between screen.

In MainWindow.xaml has `UserControl`

```
...
<UserControl Name="UserControl_UserControl" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></UserControl>
...
```

In MainWindows.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Switcher.Main = this;
    Switcher.Switch(new MainPageControl());
}

public void Navigate(UserControl nextPage)
{
    UserControl_UserControl.Content = nextPage;
    Title = "MyApp | " + nextPage.Tag;
}
```

Swither class:

```
public static class Switcher
{
    public static MainWindow Main;
    private static UserControl ShowingPage;
    private static Window PopupWindow;

    public static void Switch(UserControl newPage)
    {
        ShowingPage = newPage;
        Main.Navigate(newPage);
    }

    ......
}
```

Whereever you use Swither.Swith(...) the main window change.

Comment: Thanks, i see how it works in ur case, but it is not what i am looking for. I need to swith in ContentControl block. But thank u very much!

Comment: I do not write WPF code for a while. I am a bit rusty :) but maybe you can modify it. I use similar structure for TabControl also. I hope you can use it for ContentControl. Good luck :)